# Best Timezone practice if everything about a RoR app is based in and reflects 1 Timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

If I'm working on a Rails app (forced UTC like normal) that will have a working schedule system with a lot of dateTime interaction, but anyone that touches it (across the country) has too look at everything as "EST" (corporate thing), would you leave Rails saving records as UTC time or go with a forced EST?

I mean if everything this tool does is based in and reflects EST - is there a point to following the default practice of saving all db records as UTC?

Thanks - couldn't come up with a good search phrase for this one, I guess it's more of a "is there a an exception to the UTC only best practice" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point would be you're going to take a long walk for a short drink of water to break the UTC convention, and it's safe to assume that anything else you integrate with is going to assume times are stored in UTC. (If you start using another library that keys off time, do you really want to fork it and change their code to make sure that their times are in EST instead of UTC?)

In other words, breaking the convention is a bigger headache than going with it.

You also want to be future proof. Do you know for certain that at no point in the future you'll want to move out of EST? Probably not, and using the convention will make expanding to new markets easier :)